# Switching Between Windows of JS Page Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

Does `driver.switch_to.window` Function work with Javascript Pages for Selenium Python?

The question relates to whether driver.switch_to.window would work with JS Pages. It doesnt as per my recent finding.

I recently discovered in my project that it doesnt work.I used the work around of using the back button in browser

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pdb
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
chrome_path=r'C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe'
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
url='https://www.google.com/'
URL_List=['1line williams']


for i in range(0,2):
    driver.get(url)
    SearchPage = driver.window_handles[0]
    searchbar=driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    time.sleep(2)
    searchbar.send_keys(URL_List[i])
    searchbar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)



    if i==2:
       PipelineID=1
       SelectLink=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/a/h3').click() 

       time.sleep(2)
       Links=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("links")
       aElements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
       for name in aElements:

           window_after=driver.window_handles[0]
           time.sleep(5)
           SelectPipeline=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="splashContent_pipelines"]/div['+str(PipelineID)+']/p[2]/a[1]').click()
           time.sleep(2)
           Location=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="navmenu-v"]/li[4]/a').click()
           time.sleep(2)
           File=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="navmenu-v"]/li[4]/ul/li/a').click()
           time.sleep(15)
           document=driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')
           driver.switch_to.frame(document)
           time.sleep(2)
           DownloadFile=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="list:downloadBtn"]').click()
           time.sleep(2)
           driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-2)")
           PipelineID=PipelineID+1

           time.sleep(3)
           if PipelineID>3:
              driver.quit()
              break
```

This is the code Im using. Im using Selenium to go to google use the keyword and download data in Location column. Here I tried using `driver.switch_to.window` instead of execute script cmd at last(browser back button)but it dint work

So once again I would like to know if driver.switch_to.window works on JS Pages or not.

Comment: @DebanjanB : Can u read the question before marking? The The question relates to whether driver.switch_to.window would work with JS Pages. It doesnt deal with how to switch the window in Selenium Python

Comment: can you define "Javascript Pages"?

Comment: @Akshay What exactly do you mean by JS Pages? Can you update the question with your code trials?

Comment: @DebanjanB I have edited the post .Kindly have a look and let me know

Comment: @pcalkins.I have edited the post .Kindly have a look and let me know

Comment: Do you understand what `time.sleep(5)` is all about? What are you trying to do through `driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-2)")`?

Comment: Yes. Im trying to go back to previous window and click on another (which will be Pine and then Gul Transmission) to click on the links and donwload. I tried waiting for time.sleep and tried removing time.sleep.But it doesnt work still. Hence I used  driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-2)")instead of driver.switch to  function